# Connect 2 line phone to a 4 line system

Tags: telephone

There is a corporate phone system that uses multi-line phones.

The idea is to connect a cheap 2 line phone only for answering calls without adding a line.

Can this be done?

Just connecting in parallel doesn't work.

**Edit**
The 4 line phone is Northern Telecom Meridian.

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered without a lot more information regarding the multi-line phones.

Many later model business telephone lines use different interface protocols between the phones and control unit back in the telephone equipment room than the typical "tip and ring" connections used by a "cheap two line phone".

The business phones may be using digital signalling or a combination of digital and analog signalling. The the "cheap" phone will be using the analog type of signalling.

Comment: I added what I found. The model nº is worn out.

Comment: @fp: AFAIK Meridian is digital and incompatible with analogue handsets but check the PBX/PABX documentation.